# How to separate out int values from a string?

Tags: java

I have a variable of type `StringBuffer` which has certain numbers in it say,

```
StringBuffer newString = new StringBuffer("25 75 25");
```

Now if I want to separate this out in an integer array, how could i do it?

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfItemsInTheStore;i++){
    newString.append(values.charAt(0));
    values.deleteCharAt(0);
    char c = values.charAt(0);

    if(c==' ' || values.length()==1){
        values.deleteCharAt(0);
        value[i] = Integer.parseInt(newString.toString());
        newString.delete(0, newString.length());
        System.out.println(value[i]);
    }
}
```

What might be wrong in the program?

Comment: What about `split()`?

Comment: can you give an example? i don't know how to use it

Comment: The internet is your friend.  Attempt to search.  This isn't a training ground.

Comment: @MärmîkŠhâh [google search](https://www.google.com/?#q=string+split+java) give a bunch of result

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] splits = newString.toString().split(" ");
int[] arrInt = new int[splits.length];
int idx = 0;
for (String s: splits){
    arrInt[idx++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get String array easily and when you want to use elements as int values use Integer.parseInt() method

```
    StringBuffer newString = new StringBuffer("25 75 25"); 

    String [] strArr = newString.toString().split(" ");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
```